# reading file in python Class turns file to 0 byte, even when closed

Tags: python, class, methods

I have this weird behaviour with python class where when the text file is read it deletes everything within, leading to a 0 byte text file.

Firstly I have created a empty text file called 'file.txt'.

Then the python class is as follows

```
class File:
    def __init__(self):

        with open('/home/pi/temp/file.txt', 'r') as f:
            self.fileRead = f.readlines()
            f.close()

        self.fileWrite = open('/home/pi/temp/file.txt', 'w')

    def create(self):
        self.fileWrite.write('ABC')
        self.fileWrite.close()

    def read(self):
        for line in self.fileRead:
            print(line)
```

So to create the text file I called the `create()` method.

```
x = File()
x.create()
```

The file returns 3 bytes. - OK since it is just 'ABC'

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi    3 Jul 11 21:41  file.txt`

Now the problem is when I read the file:

```
x = File()
x.read()
```

The console prints `ABC` which is correct. But when I look at the file size, it has gone to `0` byte.

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi    0 Jul 11 21:43  file.txt`

I closed the file in the `__init__` method and have not written anything to it other than `create`, which, on the second steps it never get called?

Any idea where I made the mistakes and any better ways to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You open the file for writing with the `w` mode with

```
self.fileWrite = open('/home/pi/temp/file.txt', 'w')
```

immediately after you read it, and [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), the `w` mode truncates the file to zero bytes even if you don't write anything into it.

If

- you don't want it to be truncated, and to just continue writing at the end, use the `'a'` (append) mode. The file pointer (`.tell()`) will be at the end of the file.
- you don't want it to be truncated, and want to overwrite from the beginning, use the `'r+'` (update) mode. (The file pointer will be at the start of the file.)

Comment: I see, thanks! What would be the better way to do it? Instead of doing all the file operation in member variables, should I make another method to handle all the file operation and call within `create` and `read` method? Such that it won't get run once in the `init` method?

Comment: I'd suggest just do the file opening as part of the `create` method. Then the `create` method can handle both the file opening and closing - that's clean and encapsulated. In fact, you don't even need to make the `create` method any longer: you can use a `with` block and remove the explicit close statement, so the method will still be two lines long.

Comment: Looks messy at the moment but I think AKX `r+` update mode would work. Let me thy that for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At last I changed `w` (write) mode to `r+` (update mode) as suggested by AKX

`self.fileWrite = open('/home/pi/temp/file.txt', 'r+')`

sorry for the camel case I should have done `self.file_write` instead!